# CSS Transform not happening when generating elements programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

In this code example, I'm programmatically generating html elements, in this case meters for electricity usage per, element in the shown array.
However, when these items are being loaded, the css transition animation doesn't seem to happen.
I would like to start off the animation once the elements are loaded.

JS code:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var unit = "KWH";
var meterlistdiv = document.getElementById("meterlist");
var years = ['2021', '2020', '2019']
var values = ['500', '1000', '2000']

function selected(){
  meterlistdiv.innerHTML = '';
  unit = select.value;
  seed();
}


seed();

function seed(){

  for(var i = 0; i < years.length; i++){  


    var wrapdiv = document.createElement('div');
    wrapdiv.classList.add('wrap');

    var yearheader = document.createElement('h5');
    var yeartext = document.createTextNode(years[i]);
    yearheader.appendChild(yeartext);

    var gauge = document.createElement('div');
    gauge.appendChild(yearheader);
    gauge.classList.add('gauge');
    var gauge_body = document.createElement('div');
    gauge_body.classList.add('gauge_body');
    var gauge_fill = document.createElement('div');
    gauge_fill.classList.add('gauge_fill')
    var gauge_cover = document.createElement('div');
    gauge_cover.classList.add('gauge_cover');

    var min = document.createElement('p');
    var mintext = document.createTextNode('0');
    min.classList.add('min')
    min.appendChild(mintext);


    var max = document.createElement('p');
    var maxtext = document.createTextNode('2250');
    if(unit == 'KW'){
      maxtext = document.createTextNode('562,5');
    }
    max.classList.add('max')
    max.appendChild(maxtext);

    gauge_fill.style.transform = `rotate(${
      (values[i] / 2250) / 2
    }turn)`;
    
    gauge_cover.textContent = `${Math.round(
      (values[i] / 2250) * 100 * 22.5
    )} kWh`;

    if(unit == 'KW'){
      gauge_cover.textContent = `${Math.round(
      (values[i] / 2250 / 4) * 100 * 22.5
    )} kW`;
    }

    wrapdiv.appendChild(gauge);
    wrapdiv.appendChild(min);
    wrapdiv.appendChild(max);
    gauge.appendChild(gauge_body);
    gauge_body.appendChild(gauge_fill);
    gauge_body.appendChild(gauge_cover);
    meterlistdiv.appendChild(wrapdiv);
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
select{
  float: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -5%;
}


option{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.min{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.max{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.wrap{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gauge {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #004033;
  margin-top: -12%;
}

.gauge_body {
  float: bottom;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #b4c0be;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gauge_fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: #9acd32;
  transition-delay: 10s;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
}

.gauge_cover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Might be running too quickly, have you tried loading the elements and then pushing the animation, or using a timeout?

Comment: just tried using a timeout, yup that worked!